Correctness of algorithm to find the number of elements of order $x$ in Symmetric Group $n$?
To find the number of elements of order $x$ in $S_n$

Generate all possible partitions of $n$ by divisors of $x$.

For each partition, check if the LCM of the part lengths matches $x$.

Calculate the number of permutations based on the valid partitions.


The Python code below seems to give correct answers eg.
No. of elements of order $2$ in $S_6$ is $75$
No. of elements of order $4$ in $S_6$ is $180$
No. of elements of order $3$ in $S_{15}$ is $168369110$
Anything I might have missed or advice regarding implementation?
from math import comb, factorial, gcd
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

def divisors_of(x):
    """Return all divisors of x."""
    return [i for i in range(1, x + 1) if x % i == 0]

def lcm(numbers):
    """Calculate the least common multiple of a list of numbers."""
    return reduce(lambda x, y: (x * y) // gcd(x, y), numbers, 1)

def generate_partitions(n, divisors):
    """Generate all partitions of n using the given divisors."""
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    for i, divisor in enumerate(divisors):
        if divisor <= n:
            for subpartition in generate_partitions(n - divisor, divisors[i:]):
                yield [divisor] + subpartition

def find_valid_partitions_with_lcm(n, x):
    """Find all valid partitions of n using divisors of x where the LCM of the partition equals x."""
    valid_partitions = []
    divs = divisors_of(x)
    for partition in generate_partitions(n, divs):
        if lcm(partition) == x:
            valid_partitions.append(partition)
    return valid_partitions

def calculate_permutations(n, partitions):
    """Calculate the number of permutations for each valid partition."""
    total_permutations = 0
    for partition in partitions:
        count = 1
        remaining = n
        cycle_count = Counter(partition)
        for cycle_length in sorted(cycle_count.keys(), reverse=True):
            if cycle_length == 1:
                continue
            frequency = cycle_count[cycle_length]
            for _ in range(frequency):
                combinations = comb(remaining, cycle_length)
                permutations = factorial(cycle_length - 1)
                count *= combinations * permutations
                remaining -= cycle_length
            count //= factorial(frequency)
        total_permutations += count
    return total_permutations

def elements_of_order_in_sn(n, x):
    """Main function to find elements of order x in Sn."""
    valid_partitions = find_valid_partitions_with_lcm(n, x)
    return calculate_permutations(n, valid_partitions)

# Example usage:
n = 12  # Group size
x = 3   # Order
result = elements_of_order_in_sn(n, x)
print(f"Number of elements of order {x} in S{n}: {result}")


Please write in full sentences. Note that the $S_6=75$ and so on are bad form.

@Shaun Done that , I have. Mind yoda speak, I hope you do not.

This is very nicely written Python. I think your algorithm is very sensible and probably quite fast. I have found some tweaks that make it a bit more efficient, but they are more to do with programming than maths. You can see them here if you're interested (diff here).

@Izaak Thanks, the tweaks made it materially faster for large n and x :)

Looks correct. This is a slightly simpler way to count permutations with a given cycle structure that avoids your innermost loop. You can also avoid a bunch of list concatenation in generate_permutations by building the list as you recurse (so that you have a yield from for the recursive call). You can even avoid explicitly representing the partitions at all, and just recursively compute the desired count. This should also enable more memoization of redundant calculations.
